# Putting web Browser control and tool strip in user control...cannot control them from main form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, webbrowser-control

I am building a simple web browser in C#. In order to have all of my buttons such as the go, forward, back, refresh button, along with textbox input in a single tab, I have decided to put a tool strip and web browser control in a single user control that I created. This will enable me to just drop 1 control into a tab. Unfortunately when I try to use my user control it does not work. I know that my code inside the user control is fine, because when I had it in my main form, it functioned properly. I think the main piece that I am missing is I do not understand how to properly call the user control from the main form. Can someone guide me in the right direction here?

The main form.

```
namespace WebBrowser.UI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("random text.");
        }   
    }
}
```

And the User Control

```
namespace WebBrowser.UI
{
    public partial class adkinsBrowser : UserControl
    {
        public adkinsBrowser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

        private void toolStripButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say _"it does not work"_, what is it exactly that doesn't work? The KeyUp and KeyDown? If so, a) are you sure the UserControl has focus? b) Have tried setting the Form's [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview) property to true? More at [How to: Handle Keyboard Input at the Form Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level).

Comment: What do you mean with *properly call the user control from the main form*? Do you mean you have to add this control to the Form's Controls at run-time? Do you need the Control to return some values to the Form at some point?

Comment: I have a button and a the enter key as the controls. Outside of the user control, they work fine, but when I put them inside the user control they are not responding.

Comment: A UserControl has its own Designer. If you want to *interact* with the controls inside the UC at design-time, use the UC's Designer. At run-time, all controls behave as usual.

Comment: I believe I have done that with the second code block that I posted in my original problem statement.

Comment: "I know that my code inside the user control is fine, because when I had it in my main form, it functioned properly."  It sounds like you may have **cut and pasted** the controls from the main form into your UserControl?  If so, the handlers do not go with them (despite the code being present). Select the controls in question in your UserControl, then click on the Lightning Bolt icon in the Properties Pane to see the events for them; make sure they have the right methods associated with your desired events.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I just retyped the code inside the user control and it worked.